# How To Set Constraint To Moving Button

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

i am developing game for IOS which has 3 buttons and which moves randomly so my question is how can we set the constraint of such moving buttons using Auto-Layout?

Comment: If a button is moving through animation, what sort of constraints do you want to put on it?

Comment: the button should move on x position and i want to put constraint because it should appear properly in all IOS devices..

Answer (score 0):

You should add `IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint` and then you can move with buttons. Any like this.

```
self.someView.constant = 30;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Sorry,i am not able to understand you.Can you please explain me in brief if possible?

Comment: What do you want to move Y and X frame for UIButton?

Comment: No i just want to move the x-axis of the button and i want to set constraint so it can appear properly in all IOS devices.